# ORACLE REGEXP limitation?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I'm testing oracle `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function and regexp that works in Python or Web testing tools like https://regex101.com/ doesn't work with Oracle.

Example:

```sql
((?:NF\s{0,1}EN){0,1}[\s]{0,1}ISO[\s]{0,1}[\d]{3,6}(?:[\:]{0,1}\d{1,4}){0,1}[\-]{0,1}\d{0,1})
```

STRING: `VAS H M1582/950-80 ABCDFEF - ISO4014`

MATCH:  `ISO4014`, but oracle `regexp_like` doesn't match:

NOT MATCH:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
          'VAS H M1582/950-80 ABCDFEF - ISO4014',
          '((?:NF\s{0,1}EN){0,1}[\s]{0,1}ISO[\s]{0,1}[\d]{3,6}(?:[\:]{0,1}\d{1,4}){0,1}[\-]{0,1}\d{0,1})')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support all flavours of regular expression syntax; [see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html#GUID-969230D6-FC1A-4C75-BF2A-6B1BE909DED6).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
(NF\s?EN)?\s?ISO\s?\d{3,6}(:?\d{1,4})?-?\d?
```

See [its demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TVMDTd/1).

Note:

- Oracle regex does not "like" `[\s]`, i.e. shorthand character classes inside brackets, you should not use them like that
- `{0,1}` is equal to `?` (one or zero occurrences)
- `(?:...)`, non-capturing groups, are not supported, you should replace them with capturing groups. (Note that `(:?` is not a non-capturing group, it is just an optional colon at the start of the second capturing group in the pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my XT_REGEXP for PCRE compatible regular expressions: https://github.com/xtender/XT_REGEXP

```sql
select * 
from
 table(xt_regexp.get_matches(
  'VAS H M1582/950-80 ABCDFEF - ISO4014',
  '((?:NF\s{0,1}EN){0,1}[\s]{0,1}ISO[\s]{0,1}[\d]{3,6}(?:[\:]{0,1}\d{1,4}){0,1}[\-]{0,1}\d{0,1})'
));
```

Results:

```
COLUMN_VALUE
------------------------------
 ISO4014

1 row selected.
```